# JDK 1.7 Secure Random Generator seeding & unpredictability

Tags: java, security, random

I am planning to implement MersenneTwister algorithm for random generation. Since it is not secure, looking for setting a seed derived from SecureRandom

```
SecureRandom secureRandomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
int seedSize = 100; 
int[] seed = new int[seedSize]; 
for (int i=0; i <seedSize; i++) { 
    seed[i] = secureRandomGenerator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
}
randomGenerator = new MersenneTwister(seed);
```

I have two queries

1) Setting a seed to SHA1PRNG is bad idea or good idea?

2) If it is good idea, what is the best way to set seed for SHA1PRNG to improve unpredictability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if it's just seed, you are using it only once per application launch, so it's not a big security problem. Any good secure random algorithm (including SHA1PRNG) would be nice for the seed. The most problematic place is the Mersenne twister itself. At least it's original implementation is not secure regardless of the seed source as stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Alternatives):

> The algorithm in its native form is not cryptographically secure. The reason is that observing a sufficient number of iterations (624 in the case of MT19937, since this is the size of the state vector from which future iterations are produced) allows one to predict all future iterations.

Thus regardless of the seed source the Mersenne twister can be compromised if an attacker manages to get enough numbers from it.

Comment: So what is alternative for it?

Comment: @sunrise76, why not using SecureRandom itself instead of writing your own Mersenne twister?

Comment: I am using MT algorithm due to it's long period which is (2 power 624 - 1). The number series will be repeated only after that period, which will take years to come. This was developed around 8 years back. I am not aware of java SecureRandom period and the internals.

Comment: @sunrise76, it's completely unnecessary to observe the whole period to be able to predict the consequent numbers. Much, much shorter sequence would be enough. For example, `java.util.Random` has like `2 power 48` period, but afaik single `nextLong` result is enough to predict the subsequent numbers.

Comment: How to predict Random next values if you know nextLong?

Comment: See [this code](https://github.com/fta2012/ReplicatedRandom/blob/master/ReplicatedRandom.java#L15) for example.